# Azure Pipeline for Gradle without wrapper

Tags: gradle, azure-devops

I am creating a pipeline for a project where Gradle is used. They are not using wrapper script.
When I add the task Gradle@2, I dont see an option to run the gradle commands. it has only gradlew . even if I give gradle, it doesnt work

```js
- task: Gradle@2
  inputs:
    workingDirectory: 'AzureFunctions'
    tasks: 'jar --info'
    jdkVersionOption: '11.0.9.1'
```

Please correct me if I am using the right task for Gradle commands

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because the task is for the Gradle wrapper as explained in the documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/gradle?view=azure-devops

> Use this task to build using a **Gradle wrapper script.**

So you will need to install Gradle manually and then provide a manual task of some sort to execute `gradle`.

---

Aside, the project *should* be using the Gradle wrapper: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/gradle_wrapper.html

Comment: The project doesn't contain wrapper. Developer asked to run using gradle. Is there any task to run using gradle alone?

Answer (score 1):

@Francisco is correct, [Gradle task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/gradle?view=azure-devops) is used to build using a Gradle wrapper script. You don’t need to install Gradle if the build has a Gradle Wrapper, and use of the Gradle Wrapper is the recommended way to upgrade Gradle.

You could generate a wrapper from your Gradle project. The Gradle wrapper allows the build agent to download and configure the exact Gradle environment that is checked into the repository without having any software configuration on the build agent itself other than the JVM.

1. Create the Gradle wrapper by issuing the following command from the root project directory where your build.gradle resides:

   `jamal@fabrikam> gradle wrapper`
2. Upload your Gradle wrapper to your remote repository.

   There is a binary artifact that is generated by the gradle wrapper ( located at `gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.jar` ). This binary file is small and doesn't require updating. If you need to change the Gradle configuration run on the build agent, you update the `gradle-wrapper.properties`.

The repository should look something like this:

```
|-- gradle/
    `-- wrapper/
        `-- gradle-wrapper.jar
        `-- gradle-wrapper.properties
|-- src/
|-- .gitignore
|-- build.gradle
|-- gradlew
|-- gradlew.bat
```

Check this link for more details:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/gradle?view=azure-devops#how-do-i-generate-a-wrapper-from-my-gradle-project

If you insist on using gradle alone, you would need to configure a [self-hosted agent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/agents?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser#install) and install gradle by following the documentation below. Then use [Command Line task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/command-line?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) to run gradle.

https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/installation.html

Comment: Okay understood. I had to implement manual task as @Francisco mentioned and make this work ,because the project developer demands to use gradle alone. Thanks for your inputs guys.